# Find all cycles of given length (networkx)

Tags: graph, networkx

Given an undirected graph how do you go about finding all cycles of length n (using networkx if possible). So input would be the Graph and n and the function would return all cycles of that length.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`networkx.cycle_basis`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis.html).

```py
>>> G = networkx.Graph()
>>> networkx.add_cycle(G, [0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> networkx.add_cycle(G, [0, 3, 4, 5])
>>> print(networkx.cycle_basis(G))
[[3, 4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0]]
>>> print(networkx.cycle_basis(G, root = 2))
[[1, 2, 3, 0]]
```

Then, you can check the length of each list as you see fit.